# Javascript string coming from object comparison not working in switch

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, switch-statement

So I´m trying to compare a character stored within an object with the four cardinal points but it ain´t working. In this case, this.position.orientation value is E, but it jumps directly to the default option. I think it must be something related to trying to compare an array that is part of an object bu I have no idea how to solve it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

NOTE: the this.position.orientation was filled using previously using array.split(' ');, and it always stores just one character

```
switch (this.position.orientation) {
                case 'N':
                    this.position.orientation = 'E';
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    this.position.orientation = 'W';
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    this.position.orientation = 'S';
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    this.position.orientation = 'N';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried to put an debugger to see the this.position.orientation value? Take a look if have some white space...

Comment: It does not store any blank space, just one character (E, in this case)

Comment: What is this.position.orientation Type?

Comment: @RenatoCoqueiro it´s coming from a let aux = input.split(' ') and a following aux[2]. It stores an "E", but then the switch fails. Some casting problem?

Comment: Probably it is an array of String, and not an String. Try do use input.split(' ')[0]; just to check

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question, basically, check what is this.position.orientation before entering the switch statement and you´ll realise what the problem is about.

Comment: I know it´s an 'E' and it isn´t working. Otherwise I obviously wouldnt have asked.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is check the DataType of this.position.orientation to make sure that its an String.

I am not sure, but you are doing comparison with char. Try to use case "E" instead case 'E'.

Try use ToString() command in  this.position.orientation before compare.

If it comes from an Array, make sure that it isnt an array with only one position doing this.position.orientation[0] in switch clause.